# Why does LaTeX renewcommand not work inside tabular?

Tags: tables

I would expect the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\foo}{NO!}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
FILLER & \foo \\
\renewcommand{\foo}{YES!}%
FILLER & \foo \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

to produce

```
FILLER NO!
FILLER YES!
```

but instead I get

```
FILLER NO!
FILLER NO!
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Shamelessly copied from this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17337/14040).

> Inside a tabular cell everything is local, so changes to macros are not recognized outside the cell. Use `\gdef\foo{YES!}` instead of `\renewcommand` in the tabular environment.