# Why does additional brace group cause \settominwidth to complain about missing }

Tags: boxes, grouping

I'm using the `pbox` package's `\settominwidth` command to measure the typeset width of text that includes explicit line breaks (which is a case in which standard LaTeX's `settowidth` doesn't work).

In the following MWE, I add a brace group to localize the effect of a color switch (`\color{red}`). Adding the brace group causes an error when that command is passed to `\settominwidth`: `Missing } inserted.`

I'd like to know what's illegitimate about adding the brace group. (Note that the color switch without the added brace group, in `\textA`, doesn't raise a complaint.)

I'm also curious why `\settominwidth` reports about 2pt more width for `\widthB` than for `\widthA`, but that's not a mandatory part of the solution.

I realize that, in this limited MWE, I could avoid the issue by using `\textcolor{red}{someText}` instead, but this MWE is abstracted from a larger context in which a switch is preferable.

Stack Exchange suggested as a "similar question": "[Why can't I use braces in an \if… \fi group?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320491/why-cant-i-use-braces-in-an-if-fi-group)". Perhaps it holds the key, but I don't know enough about `\settominwidth` to know.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newlength{\widthA}
\newlength{\widthB}
\newcommand{\textA}{\color{blue} One \\ Two}
\newcommand{\textB}{{\color{red} One \\ Two}}

\settominwidth{\widthA}{\textA}
\settominwidth{\widthB}{\textB}

\begin{document}
\texttt{\textbackslash{}widthA}: \the\widthA\\
\texttt{\textbackslash{}widthB}: \the\widthB

\textA

\textB

After text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\settominwidth` uses internally a tabular. This means that you are doing

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
{\color{red} One \\ Two}
\end{tabular}
```

And this doesn't work as cell are groups.

Comment: what would be the general formulation of what you _can't_ do in the argument of `\settominwidth`? Is it just that you can't encapsulate the entire argument in a brace group? Or is it more general than that?