# Redefine command depending on options

Tags: conditionals

I would like to change a parameter depending on the option in Beamer class. If [handout] is set, I want to show graphics smaller. To do this, I was creating a boolean `\ifhandout`and was trying to redefine another variable `\Skalierung` depending whether `\ifhandout` is True or False. It doesn't work. Any idea why the if-statement doesn't work?

Thank you very much,

Markus

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\makeatletter
\newif\ifhandout
\@ifclasswith{beamer}{handout}{\handouttrue}{\handoutfalse}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\Skalierung}{1.0}

\begin{document}
    \ifhandout{Handout} % This works
    \else{Presentation}
    \fi

    \ifhandout{\renewcommand{\Skalierung}{0.3}} % This doesn't work
    \else{\renewcommand{\Skalierung}{0.7}}}
    \fi

    \Skalierung % Skalierung is always 1
\end{document}
```

Comment: The braces are the problem: remove them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I use braces in an \if... \fi group?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320491/why-cant-i-use-braces-in-an-if-fi-group)

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick help