# Command or Environment to generate a table row

Tags: tables, pdftex, forms

I'm creating a PDF form with the help of the hyperref package, which has a survey format. After looking around, I've grouped the survey statements into tables, like this:

```
    \begin{Form}
      \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xcccc}
        \toprule
        \large \textbf{Sozialverhalten} & A & B & C & D \\
        \midrule
        This is the first survey statement & 
          \rule[6pt]{0pt}{6pt}\hbox{\CheckBox[print,name=2, width=0.7em, height=0.7em]{}} &
          \rule[6pt]{0pt}{6pt}\hbox{\CheckBox[print,name=2, width=0.7em, height=0.7em]{}} &
          \rule[6pt]{0pt}{6pt}\hbox{\CheckBox[print,name=2, width=0.7em, height=0.7em]{}} &
          \rule[6pt]{0pt}{6pt}\hbox{\CheckBox[print,name=2, width=0.7em, height=0.7em]{}} \\
        \midrule
        This is the second survey statement &
          \rule[6pt]{0pt}{6pt}\hbox{\CheckBox[print,name=2, width=0.7em, height=0.7em]{}} &
          \rule[6pt]{0pt}{6pt}\hbox{\CheckBox[print,name=2, width=0.7em, height=0.7em]{}} &
          \rule[6pt]{0pt}{6pt}\hbox{\CheckBox[print,name=2, width=0.7em, height=0.7em]{}} &
          \rule[6pt]{0pt}{6pt}\hbox{\CheckBox[print,name=2, width=0.7em, height=0.7em]{}} \\
        \midrule
                  [ ... ]
    \end{Form}
```

I would like to use a macro / command for each row of the table which would take as an argument, the text of the first column and generate the checkboxes (columns 2-4), which are the same for each row, automatically. Or alternatively write a command, which can generate the checkboxes. How can I do this? Do I need a new command or an environment?

Comment: Well, I want to be able to write _in_ the table: `surveyrow{This is the statement}` and it generates a complete table row. That would avoid copy-and-pasting all the checkbox code, which would save me a lot of time and effort!

Comment: If you use the same name for every \CheckBox, you will switch them all on or off together.  Using macros inside tabulars often leads to problems ( see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17335/macro-behaviour-different-inside-tabular-environment?s=6|0.6932)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just put the necessary bits in a new command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\newcounter{row}

\newcommand{\makerow}[1]{%
 % #1 = text field
 #1 &
 \stepcounter{row}%
 \mbox{\CheckBox[print,name=A\therow, width=0.7em, height=0.7em]{}} &
 \mbox{\CheckBox[print,name=B\therow, width=0.7em, height=0.7em]{}} &
 \mbox{\CheckBox[print,name=C\therow, width=0.7em, height=0.7em]{}} &
 \mbox{\CheckBox[print,name=D\therow, width=0.7em, height=0.7em]{}} \\
}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xcccc}
\toprule
\textbf{Sozialverhalten} & A & B & C & D \\
\midrule
\makerow{This is the first survey statement}
\midrule
\makerow{This is the second survey statement}
\midrule
\makerow{This is the third survey statement, quite long to produce a line break}
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks egreg, this is what I was trying to do, but I was getting an error-- something about an environment, I think. Perhaps it was due to me including the \midrule in the command? Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @timeout Environments inside a tabular? No, you cannot safely generate a row using an environment, without special tricks.

Answer (score 2):

I avoided the problem of using `tabularx` or `tabular` by using `\parbox` and `\makebox`.  You can use `\settowidth` on a `\CheckBox`, but I was uncomfortable doing so.

Interestingly, without the `\hbox` the `\Checkbox` grew larger every time I made `\mystrut` bigger.  Also, if you put a `\Checkbox` inside a `\fbox` you will see that it is not centered in the area.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\newcounter{row}
\newlength{\Xwidth}
\newlength{\Bwidth}

\newcommand{\makerow}[1]% #1 = textfield
{\hrule\stepcounter{row}%
  \mystrut\hspace{2\tabcolsep}%
  \parbox[t]{\Xwidth}{#1}\hfil
  \hbox{\CheckBox[name=A\therow, width=0.7em, height=0.7em]{}}\hfil
  \hbox{\CheckBox[name=B\therow, width=0.7em, height=0.7em]{}}\hfil
  \hbox{\CheckBox[name=C\therow, width=0.7em, height=0.7em]{}}\hfil
  \hbox{\CheckBox[name=D\therow, width=0.7em, height=0.7em]{}}%
\par}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\parindent=0pt
\large% changes size of em
\setlength{\Bwidth}{\dimexpr 0.7em+4pt}% width of \CheckBox
\setlength{\Xwidth}{\dimexpr \textwidth-12\tabcolsep-4\Bwidth}% width of parbox
\def\mystrut{\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr 0.7em + \tabcolsep}\rule[-\tabcolsep]{0pt}{0pt}}%

\hrule height1pt
\mystrut\hspace{2\tabcolsep}%
 \parbox[t]{\Xwidth}{\textbf{Sozialverhalten}}\hspace{2\tabcolsep}%
 \makebox[\Bwidth][r]{A}\hspace{2\tabcolsep}%
 \makebox[\Bwidth][r]{B}\hspace{2\tabcolsep}%
 \makebox[\Bwidth][r]{C}\hspace{2\tabcolsep}%
 \makebox[\Bwidth][r]{D}\hspace*{2\tabcolsep}%

\makerow{This is the first survey statement}
\makerow{This is the second survey statement}
\hrule height1pt
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Wow! Thanks, John! Great information about the use of the name attr. in Checkbox as well. There's a lot I can learn and look into from this example.